# PySpark - Convert an RDD into a key value pair RDD, with the values being in a List

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, key-value

I have an RDD with tuples being in the form:

```
[("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1"), ("a2","b2","c2","d2","e2"), ...
```

What I want is to transform that into a key-value pair RDD, where the first field will be the first string (key) and the second field a list of strings (value), i.e. I want to turn it to the form:

```
[("a1",["b1","c1","d1","e1"]), ("a2",["b2","c2","d2","e2"]), ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1"), ("a2","b2","c2","d2","e2")])

>>> result = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1:])))

>>> print result.collect()
[('a1', ['b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1']), ('a2', ['b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'])]
```

Explanation of `lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1:]))`:

1. `x[0]` will make the first element to be the first element of the
   output
2. `x[1:]` will make all the elements except the first one to be
   in the second element
3. `list(x[1:])` will force that to be a list
   because the default will be a tuple